# Can I add non-capture groups with a list of optional characters?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I need to match strings which have `a-z`, `\?` or `\*`, for example:

```
abcd
abc\?d # mush have a \ in front of a ?
abc\*d
ab\?c\*d
```

and exclude strings which don't have `\` in front of other punctuations, such as

```
abc?d
abc*d
ab?c*d
```

I tried `[a-z(?:\\\?)(?:\\\*)]+` (https://regex101.com/r/5yYBDl/1), but it doesn't work, because `[]` only supports characters i guess.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex with an alternation and anchors:

```sh
^(?:[a-z]|\\[*?])+$
```

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5yYBDl/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:[a-z]|\\[*?])+`: Non capturing group to match either `[a-z]` or `\?` or `\*`. Match 1 or more of this non capturing group.
- `$`: End

Answer (score 0):

will match Unicode character work? depending on your application it may have Unicode support

```
^(?:[a-z]|\u005c[\u003f\u002a])+$
```

https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html 
snippet from this site 
"Perl, PCRE, Boost, and std::regex do not support the \uFFFF syntax. They use \x{FFFF} instead. You can omit leading zeros in the hexadecimal number between the curly braces. Since \x by itself is not a valid regex token, \x{1234} can never be confused to match \x 1234 times. It always matches the Unicode code point U+1234. \x{1234}{5678} will try to match code point U+1234 exactly 5678 times"

Comment: `\?` is not one unicode character, it's literally \ and ?

Comment: try [a-z\u005c]+

Comment: [\u005c]+  is \       [\u003f]+  is ?

Comment: sorry i'm a bit confused. \u005c and \u003f are still 2 characters, how do i match `\?` without matching `?` alone?

Comment: ^(?:[a-z]|\u005c[\u003f\u002a])+$

Comment: sorry i read "only supports characters" and got tunnel vision. the fix was more about the function format